# Action AFTER render/ load tab in tabview in PrimeFaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, primefaces

I am searching solution of PrimeFaces problem.
I have a simple code:

```
<p:tabView id="tabView" dynamic="true">
        <p:ajax event="tabChange" oncomplete="setActiveTabIndex(); alert('after tab change')" listener="#{backingBean.onTabChange}"/>
        <p:tab titletip="Tab 1">
            <ui:include ... />      
        </p:tab>
        <p:tab titletip="Tab 2">
            <ui:include .../>
        </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

And  I must call JavaScript action after render page after click on tab (include page). Actually js from oncomplete action is called after click on tab - before render page from tab ...

PS: my primeFaces version is : 6.0
Regards

Comment: See https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/remoteCommand.xhtml

Comment: In spite of <p:remoteCommand autoRun="true" .../> which is in included site, this run also after click, but before render page